# How to start task only when first 3 letters of hostname are equal to a specific word in ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, debian

I am new to ansible and hanging on following problem:
I have written a task, which should only be startet when the first three letters of the remote hostname is equal to "abc".
I got the hostname by following task:

```
- name: register hostname
      slurp:
        src: /etc/hostname
      register: hostname
```

Now, i want to copy a file from remote to my local machine:

```
 - name: copy backup
   fetch:
     src: /xxx/xxx/
     dest: /xxx/xxx/xxx/
     fail_on_missing: yes
```

Everything i trie with regex_search or split to safe the hostname in another var which i would compare to "abc" doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to compare the first 3 characters from the hostname variable.

Here is my snippet

```
  - name: register hostname
    set_fact:
      hostname: "abc-def-ghi"

  - name: copy backup (should skip)
    debug:
      msg: "it doesn't start with abc"
    when: hostname[0:3] == "def"

  - name: copy backup (should execute)
    debug:
      msg: "it starts with abc"
    when: hostname[0:3] == "abc"
```

And the results

```
TASK [register hostname] *******************************************************************************
Tuesday 30 March 2021  08:01:39 -0400 (0:00:00.044)       0:00:00.044 ********* 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [copy backup (should skip)] ***********************************************************************
Tuesday 30 March 2021  08:01:39 -0400 (0:00:00.035)       0:00:00.080 ********* 
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [copy backup (should execute)] ********************************************************************
Tuesday 30 March 2021  08:01:40 -0400 (0:00:00.099)       0:00:00.180 ********* 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "it starts with abc"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer!
It works as you said :)
But if i try to build this in my copy task, i get a error.
Task:
    - name: copy backup
      fetch:
        src: /etc/backuptest
        dest: /home/osboxes/testRundeck
      when: hostname[0:3] == "3cx"`


I think it's because of the fetch module, but i don't know where the error is... :(
Error: *
fatal: [server_debian]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.178.102 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n [...]

Comment: Hard to tell with this information. I would check permissions issue on the file both local and remote. You can also use Ansible-playbook -v (or -vvvv) to get a more detailed error message.